Hugo site works perfectly via Netlify & localhost, but incomplete via GitHub Pages
I've migrated my Hugo blog/portfolio from Netlify to Github Pages, and am running into an issue with three select folders (under /content folder) returning 404 inaccessible when deployed via GitHub Pages. Other than those folders, the rest of the site functions correctly.
Everything worked fine on Netlify and still does locally with hugo server (localhost:1313/).
However, GitHub just doesn't like just these few pages. I even tried temporarily rigging an index.html to redirect to the old Netlify deploy (still functioning), but even then GitHub returns 404.
The folders/files in question are traditional HTML and Javascript (instead of Markdown), and I'm wondering if that has anything to do with it?
repository -- https://github.com/NicholiNoah/NicholiNoah
page in question -- https://nicholinoah.com/gift/ckeesee/sunset
still working on old Netlify deploy -- https://main--jolly-brown-a2702d.netlify.app/gift/ckeesee/sunset
**note: the only reason I left Netlify was because this over-bandwidth charge that happened in February unfortunately scared me away.
What I've tried to fix: (ChatGPT helped me get this far, but I haven't been able to wrestle a solution to the above issue.)
I followed the https://gohugo.io/hosting-and-deployment/hosting-on-github/ instructions to get Hugo working on GHPages. I expected the site to function as it did on Netlify and still does on localhost:1313, but select pages do not function as intended.
I also made sure the new github/workflows/hugo.yaml file indicates the exact same Hugo version as original netlify.toml file. This caused a GitHub deploy error, so I returned it to 0.123.0 (that deployed correctly via GitHub Pages).
I'm getting a content-security-policy error in browser, but don't know how to address that.

Hugo no longer displaying page
The issue stems from a breaking change introduced in Hugo 0.123.0 that introduced stricter rules on how the Hugo interpreter handles raw (those without frontmatter/templates) HTML files in the content directory. Previously, Hugo would serve raw HTML files directly, but now it requires proper Hugo structure and templates.
Here's some related reading from the Hugo repo going over the changes and their motivations:

Hugo PR about changing the way HTML is displayed
Hugo issue about the way HTML was treated prior to 0.123.0
Hugo release notice for version 0.123.0 which mentions breaking changes

There are (at least) 2 solutions:
1. Use Hugo 0.122.0
Modify your .github/workflows/hugo.yaml:
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    env:
      HUGO_VERSION: 0.122.0

This will render sunset.html as you previously had it (I tested it by forking your repo).
It's not the best option long-term because:

You'll miss security updates and new features
Future Hugo updates might introduce additional problems that will need these current ones fixed

But hey, these are problems for later down the road, solution 1 will work for now. However if you want to fix the problem permanently, well then I recommend solution 2:
2. Create proper Hugo structure

Create a layout template for a single page at layouts/_default/single.html

{{ .Content }}

This page variable will mean that the all the Content of the content page (the content page in this case is sunset.html) is rendered, Hugo knows that the content page is of type HTML so it will parse the HTML correctly (instead of just having the raw HTML be displayed, <'s and all).

Add Frontmatter to sunset.html

Frontmatter allows more control over your Hugo site, both by you and by Hugo. Though not strictly required for this use-case (sunset.html will render without it), it would be good practice to add some to the file.
(As an aside, if you use the Hugo CLI that comes installed with Hugo to create content via hugo new <CONTENT-NAME>, then your existing archetype file will be inherited by that content file, meaning the frontmatter will be created automatically.)
---
title: "Sunset"
date: 2024-11-19
draft: false
---
/* rest of sunset.html */

Why this Works
The original setup treated sunset.html as a content page. From Hugo version 0.123.0 onward, raw HTML files without front matter are no longer automatically processed as content pages. By adding the front matter and layout template, we explicitly tell Hugo that it is a content page (made up of an HTML file with frontmatter) and how to render it (with the layout template).
Putting single.html in layouts/_default/ will mean all individual content pages (any page that isn't a list/homepage, how to tell the difference here) will use that layout. If it causes more changes than you'd like, then you can restrict the layout file to affect just the content pages under content/gift by moving single.html to layouts/gift/single.html.
Content Security Policy
The content-security-policy error you mentioned requires more information to resolve and is a little outside of the scope of your Hugo deployment problem. If you're still having issues with it feel free to create another separate question and I'll do my best to assist you (include the exact CSP error from your browser).
In the meantime here's a Stackoverflow reply that can give some information on what kind of issue a CSP issue is. It includes a link to the relevant Mozilla developer page and a link to the Google CSP Evaluator which is a tool that can look at your Content Security Policy and find problems. Give it a try, hopefully it can help.
